# Is it possible to find set of functions so that their antiderivatives are also in this set?

Tags: integration, functions, elementary-functions

Antiderivatives of elementary functions sometimes are not elementary functions.

Is it possible to add finite number of non-elementary functions to elementary function set so that their antiderivatives are also in this set?

Comment: Can you be specific about what you call elementary functions ?

Comment: An elementary function is a function of one variable built from a finite number of exponentials, logarithms, constants, trigonometric functions and real powers through composition and combinations using the addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Comment: @Git: the previous definition includes polynomials. And all powers are implicit as well. Trigonometric functions can be generated from exponentials and logarithms if complex numbers are allowed. (Even multiplication and division can be skipped :) )

Comment: The answer is most probably negative, otherwise these extra functions would be described in every textbook.

Comment: I don't know about "finite number", but a class which is closed under most operations you can think of is Meijer G-functions (use Google for more info).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Maybe it's possible to prove that by contradiction?

Comment: @HansLundmark It's kind of cheating, that function has many parameters!